# Rain drop trails on a car window prefer certain paths. Why?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, water, stability

> Why do the raindrops always flow down in the middle?

That's a question given to me by my seven year old son.

---

Some background:

We are sitting in a bus with two windscreen wiper blades.

I hope that the image below explains the situation well

- The image on the right shows the range of the windscreen wiper blades.
- The image on the left is the same image with only an arrow pointing towards the place where the drops continuously start to make a trail. (There are also other trails in the image, but in that point in the middle there is ever time a trail and often very directly and the first compared to the other trails)

[image: example image]

My son believes that it is because the water flows from two sides such that it creates a stronger force. Possibly this intuition makes sense that holds in a more formal formulation?

I believe that some sort of instability plays a role which has a faster growth rate at the pointy edge of the intersection of the trails from the two windshield blades. But the exact mechanism might be complicated. The trails resemble some combination of [Rayleigh Taylor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Taylor_instability) instability (due to wind/air pushing the liquid film on the window?) and [tears of wine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tears_of_wine).

Comment: Is the same phenomenon observed when the car is not moving with respect to the air?

Comment: @gs We have only made clear observations during movement of the car (actually it is a bus). We also noticed that when the bus stopped that water was suddenly flowing down via other trails. However, that is not so surprising and it must have been water from the roof that went forward while the bus is braking. I don't recall so well, but I believe that during the longer stops the trails were also present (not just when the bus was moving) and the middle path was still a preference.

Comment: Actually, this particular image seems to have been taken at a busstop (the yellow markings on the left). My very crappy phone camera has much troubles making quick images recently and at a busstop it possibly performs better (it is this Samsung 9 thing, that makes very nice images by composing multiple images from different lenses together, but also very slow). In this image the bus seems to be standing still or only just moving (slow speed). The cars in the view must have just passed the bus. But I am not sure about the wind conditions,

Comment: On possibility - the non-wiper swept portions of the window are dirtier, and water will stick to the dirtier part of the window. But, it also wants to flow down under gravity. The bead of water on the edge of the wiped portions channels it down toward the middle, the V between the wiper areas, where it finally overcomes surface tension and runs down the wiped area.

Comment: @JonCuster *"where it finally overcomes surface tension"* This might be an interesting part of an explanation. Why wouldn't a drop of water on a window not just flow down (a more general question than the one I posed here)? It has to overcome some force/barrier. But what is that barrier? A drop of water is being pulled down by gravity, and which forces are holding it back? Sure it's surface tension, but how does that do it exactly, why don't the drops just slide down without changing shape? The change of the drop from one position to another is not requires passing some barrier.

Comment: This sounds a bit like some variant of a capillary force.